A confusion on the $T$-matrix in scattering theory
In scattering theory,
the Lippmann-Schwinger equation gives
$$|\psi^{+}\rangle=|\phi\rangle+G_{0}V |\psi^{+}\rangle,$$ where  $(E-H)|\psi^{+}\rangle=0$ and $(E-H_{0})|\phi\rangle=0$, $$G_{0}=(E-H_{0}+\mathrm{i}\epsilon)^{-1}$$ and $H=H_{0}+V$.
According to the optical theorem, the total cross section is associated with the imaginary part of a $T$-matrix element  which is given as $\langle \phi|V|\psi^{+}\rangle$.
One might find
$$
\langle \phi|V|\psi^{+}\rangle=\langle \phi|(E-H_{0})|\psi^{+}\rangle, 
$$ since $(E-H)|\psi^{+}\rangle=0$.
On one hand, due to the equation $$[(E-H_{0})|\phi\rangle]^{\dagger}=0,$$ the above quantity seems always become zero, however on the other hand
$$\langle \phi|(E-H_{0})|\psi^{+}\rangle=\langle \phi|(E-H_{0})(|\phi\rangle+G_{0}V|\phi\rangle+G_{0}VG_{0}V|\phi\rangle+\cdots)=\langle\phi| T|\phi\rangle$$ gives the right result.
I am confused that how the contradiction arises here.

You are somewhat sloppy with $i\epsilon$, which is present in your last equation, but not in the one that is identically zero.

Could you elaborate how you obtained your first (non-trivial) equation? I.e. the one after "one might find"

Since $(E-H)|\psi^{+}\rangle=(E-H_{0}-V)|\psi^{+}\rangle=0$, it gives  $(E-H_{0})|\psi^{+}\rangle=V|\psi^{+}\rangle$.

I see. If I had to guess I'd say that the problem here is that both vectors are in fact not vectors in the Hilbert space, i.e. they are "generalized eigenvectors" of the relevant Hamiltonians and belong to the continuous spectrum. Hence, we need extra care when making such manipulations.

As suggested by Roger V. in the comments, everything works out if you don't set $i\epsilon$ to zero prematurely.
Acting with $E-H_0+i\epsilon$ on both sides of the Lippmann Schwinger equation, you get,
$$(E-H_0+i\epsilon)|\psi^+\rangle=i\epsilon |\phi\rangle+V|\psi^+\rangle,$$
which suggests
$$(E-H)|\psi^+\rangle=-i\epsilon\left(|\psi^+\rangle-|\phi\rangle\right)=-i\epsilon G_0V|\psi^+\rangle.$$
Ordinarily we can set $\epsilon$ to zero on the right side, but if the $E-H_0$ factor in the denominator of $G_0$ vanishes (which is exactly what happens when $\langle\phi|$ acts on the left) then there is a compensating $i\epsilon$ in the denominator of $G_0$.
Doing your same manipulations
$$\langle \phi|H-H_0|\psi^+\rangle = \langle \phi|E-H_0|\psi^+\rangle +i\epsilon\langle \phi|G_0 V|\psi^+\rangle.$$
Now the first term vanishes as in your question, but the second term indeed equals the left hand side.

Thanks for Roger V.'s comment and your answer. I see the problem I confronted seems come from the infinity (or ill-define as it was suggested by Tobias Fünke) of the inner product $\langle\phi|\psi^{+}\rangle$
and to add an $\mathrm{i}\epsilon$
term could guide me to the right result.

Just to be clear, I am suggesting that $|\psi^+\rangle$ is only an eigenvector of $H$ after you set the $i\epsilon$ term in the expression to zero, but you can not set it to zero when you act on the left with $\langle \phi|$. This has nothing directly to do with the inner product diverging.

The answer does not address the issue in the OP why the first derivation of $\langle \phi, V\psi^+\rangle=0$ is incorrect--note that the derivation OP gave in a comment under the question does not make use of the Lippmann-Schwinger equation at all. One just assumes that $\psi^+$ and $\phi$ are (generalized) eigenvectors of $H$ and $H_0$, respectively, with the same energy $E$.

@TobiasFünke, My answer directly addresses that issue. What I did with the Lippmann-Schwinger equation is how you show that $|\psi^+\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $H$ in the first place. Ordinarily you drop the $i\epsilon$ term. My answer is stating that you can not consider $|\psi^+\rangle$ to be an eigenvector in this situation because the $i\epsilon$ term can not be dropped, and that is what is going wrong in the question.

The crux of the matter is that OP by replacing $$V|\psi^+\rangle\quad\to\quad(E-H_0+i\epsilon)|\psi^+\rangle\tag{A}$$ is effectively undoing/unravelling the otherwise well-defined perturbative expansion $$\begin{align}|\psi^+\rangle~:=~&\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}(G_0V)^n|\phi\rangle\cr
~=~&|\phi\rangle+G_0V|\psi^+\rangle, \cr 
G_0~:=~&(E-H_0+i\epsilon)^{-1},\end{align}\tag{B}$$
of the Lippmann-Schwinger (LS) formalism (at least as a formal power series); thereby exposing the short-comings of the heuristic proof given on e.g. the Wikipedia page, especially wrt. the treatment of the $i\epsilon$-regularization, of (among other things) the TISE:
$$\begin{align}  G_0(E-H+i\epsilon)|\psi^+\rangle  
~\stackrel{(B)+(D)}{=}~&(1-G_0V)\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}(G_0V)^n|\phi\rangle\cr
~\stackrel{\text{geom. series}}{=}&|\phi\rangle,\cr
(E-H_0)|\phi\rangle~\stackrel{\text{TISE}}{=}~~~&0,
\end{align}\tag{C}$$
where
$$ H~:=~H_0+V. \tag{D}$$

The answer does not address the issue in the OP why the first derivation of $\langle \phi, V\psi^+\rangle=0$ is incorrect--note that the derivation OP gave in a comment under the question does not make use of the Lippmann-Schwinger equation at all. One just assumes that $\psi^+$ and $\phi$ are (generalized) eigenvectors of $H$ and $H_0$, respectively, with the same energy $E$.

I updated the answer.

Unlike the previous answerers, I think your problem is instead this:
If $(E-H)\left|\psi^+\right>=0$, then $(E-H_0)\left|\phi\right>\neq0$
By that I mean that if you have a perturbation, it ought not to keep the energy eigenvalue the same. If, instead, you had $(E_0-H_0)$, it would have made more sense, but then it will definitely not agree with your manipulations.

It is a scattering problem - the goal here is finding the structure of the solution that is asymptotically the solution of the same energy in absence of the perturbation. Unfortunately, basic qm texts do poor job explaining difference between eigenvalue and scattering problems.

That's part of it, but also it is very annoying that textbooks tend to overlook some facts: we usually want to study the scattering under the Coulomb potential, but that fundamentally alters everything. The results tend to be the same, but the Coulomb potential decays slowly enough to alter the wavefunction even at infinitely far away, so that most treatments' assumptions dont work.
